# Using the correct oauth2 credentials to connect to AzureDevops through NodeJS using Passport.js

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, passport.js

I am having issues to figure out what exact credentials I have to use to connect to Azure Devops through NodeJS using Passport.js.

I am using the strategy as described here: http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-azure-oauth2/

In AzureDevops, I have created an Application under the: Authorized OAuth Apps, and then have the following information at my disposal there:

[image]
This is the current code I use to create the strategy:

```
passport.use("azure-devops", new AzureOAuth2Strategy({
  clientID: process.env.AZURE_DEVOPS_CLIENT_ID,
  clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_DEVOPS_CLIENT_SECRET,
  callbackURL: process.env.AZURE_DEVOPS_CALLBACK_URL,
  resource: process.env.AZURE_DEVOPS_RESOURCE,
  tenant: process.env.AZURE_DEVOPS_TENANT,
  prompt: 'consent',
  state: true
},
function (accessToken, refreshtoken, params, profile, done) {
  var user = jwt.decode(params.id_token, "", true);
  done(null, user);
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
   done(null, user)
})
passport.deserializeUser(function(obj, done) {
   done(null, obj)
});

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
```

Now what I do not understand is which information to fill into the respective credentials fields. Especially confusing to me are the fields "tenant" and the field "resource". Passport.js describes these fields as optional, however, if I leave the "tenant" field out, when I go to the microsoft login page using the /auth/login route, I am getting into a loop. It means that when I enter my email and password, it redirects me back to the login and this is endless. If I add the "tenant" field with an ID (where I am not sure of which ID I need to use).
I receive the following error:

[image]

What am I supposed to add to these fields in the Strategy and where do I find this information???

Also confusing to me is that after I have added my application and I go to the dashboard about added applications, it says I have not granted access to any application yet, although I have added that application before ... it looks like this on my side:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passport-azure-oauth2 strategy is used to authenticate to access **Azure Resources** not **Azure devops**. This strategy is actually the Azure [OAuth 2.0 client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

If you want to use Oauth2 as authentication for azure devops. You should use OAuth2 authorization code grant flow.  See below document for more information.

[Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops). There is a [sample project](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/tree/master/OAuthWebSample) you can check out.

There are many ways to authenticate your application with Azure DevOps Services. Check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1#authenticate) for more examples.

As for Passport.js, you can check out [OAuth2orize](https://github.com/jaredhanson/oauth2orize) which is a sibling project to Passport, provides a toolkit for implementing OAuth 2.0 authorization servers.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I kind of had the idea that this is not the right way to do it and I thought I could use passport.js exclusively for this but it seems I cannot. 
I also also found this official microsoft connecting AzureDevops using OAuth2: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops. I will check out the sample project you sent, I think it will help me implementing it correctly. Marking it as correct answer.